SpringBoot 3.3 RestClient with Proxy and Authenication gives 401 response
Initializing proxy and basic authentication throws 401 unauthorized error and check the logs for the below code gives No credentials for basic schema DEBUG log is seen
proxyUrl = "proxy.ops.org";
proxyport = 8080;
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials( 
    new AuthScope(proxyUrl, proxyport), 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)
);

HttpHost myProxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl, proxyport);
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
clientBuilder.setProxy(myProxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider); 
clientBuilder.setProxy(myProxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
factory.setHttpClient(httpClient); 

RestClient rstCleint = RestClient.builder
                .baseUrl("http://test.org")
                .requestFactory(factory)
                .build();

Rest Api call to external api from spring boot
            ResponseEntity<String> result = restClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve().toEntity(String.class)

Debug Logs.
13:22:52.369 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
13:22:54.309 DEBUG i.o.e.t.p.B3PropagatorExtractorMultipleHeaders - Invalid TraceId in B3 header: null'. Returning INVALID span context.
13:22:54.309 DEBUG i.o.e.t.p.B3PropagatorExtractorMultipleHeaders - Invalid TraceId in B3 header: null'. Returning INVALID span context.
13:22:54.309 DEBUG i.m.t.o.p.BaggageTextMapPropagator - Will propagate new baggage context for entries {}
13:22:54.324 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - GET "/favicon.ico", parameters={}
13:22:54.334 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
13:22:54.338 DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Resource not found
13:22:54.349 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Using @ExceptionHandler org..changeautomation.configuration.CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler#handleException(Exception, WebRequest)
13:22:54.437 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Using 'application/problem+json;q=0.8', given [image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, image/svg+xml, image/*, */*;q=0.8] and supported [application/problem+json]
13:22:54.442 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing [ProblemDetail[type='about:blank', title='Not Found', status=404, detail='No static resource favicon. (truncated)...]
13:22:54.461 WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource favicon.ico.]
13:22:54.461 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
13:23:06.676 DEBUG i.o.e.t.p.B3PropagatorExtractorMultipleHeaders - Invalid TraceId in B3 header: null'. Returning INVALID span context.
13:23:06.676 DEBUG i.o.e.t.p.B3PropagatorExtractorMultipleHeaders - Invalid TraceId in B3 header: null'. Returning INVALID span context.
13:23:06.676 DEBUG i.m.t.o.p.BaggageTextMapPropagator - Will propagate new baggage context for entries {}
13:23:06.677 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - GET "/changeautomation/releasewindows", parameters={}
13:23:06.678 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org..changeautomation.controller.ChangeRequestController#getApplicationReleaseWindows()
13:23:17.781 INFO  o.t.c.s.i.CDPortfolioServiceImpl - applicationWindowsURL is /api/now/table/u_release_types?sysparm_query=u_inactive%3Dfalse%5Eu_release_typeNOT%20LIKENonProd%5Eu_category%3DTGAM%20Release%5EORu_category%3DApplication%20Release%5EORDERBYu_release_start&sysparm_fields=sys_id%2Cu_release_type%2Cu_category%2Cu_release_month%2Cu_release_start%2Cu_release_end%2Cu_release_number
14:14:44.786 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.InternalHttpClient - ex-0000000001 preparing request execution
14:14:44.866 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.ProtocolExec - ex-0000000001 target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
14:14:44.872 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.ConnectExec - ex-0000000001 acquiring connection with route {tls}->http://proxy.ops.-cref.org:8080->https://test.org:443
14:14:44.879 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.InternalHttpClient - ex-0000000001 acquiring endpoint (3 MINUTES)
14:14:44.891 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ex-0000000001 endpoint lease request (3 MINUTES) [route: {tls}->http://proxy.ops.-cref.org:8080->https://test.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 25]
14:14:44.927 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ex-0000000001 endpoint leased [route: {tls}->http://proxy.ops.-cref.org:8080->https://test.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 25]
14:14:45.055 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ex-0000000001 acquired ep-0000000001
14:14:45.056 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.InternalHttpClient - ex-0000000001 acquired endpoint ep-0000000001
14:14:45.057 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.ConnectExec - ex-0000000001 opening connection {tls}->http://proxy.ops.-cref.org:8080->https://test.org:443
14:14:45.061 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000001 connecting endpoint (null)
14:14:45.071 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000001 connecting endpoint to http://proxy.ops.-cref.org:8080 (3 MINUTES)
14:14:45.072 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - proxy.ops.-cref.org resolving remote address
14:14:45.076 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - proxy.ops.-cref.org resolved to [proxy.ops.-cref.org/10.136.192.72]
14:14:45.092 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - proxy.ops.-cref.org:8080 connecting null->proxy.ops.-cref.org/10.136.192.72:8080 (3 MINUTES)
14:14:45.099 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0 set socket timeout to 3 MINUTES
14:14:45.100 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - proxy.ops.-cref.org:8080 connected null->proxy.ops.-cref.org/10.136.192.72:8080 as http-outgoing-0
14:14:45.101 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000001 connected http-outgoing-0
14:14:45.102 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000001 endpoint connected
14:14:45.104 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000001 start execution ex-0000000001
14:14:45.105 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000001 executing exchange ex-0000000001 over http-outgoing-0
14:14:45.110 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> CONNECT test.org:443 HTTP/1.1
14:14:45.111 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: test.org:443
14:14:45.112 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.9)
14:14:45.114 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "CONNECT test.org:443 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
14:14:45.115 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: test.org:443[\r][\n]"
14:14:45.116 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.9)[\r][\n]"
14:14:45.117 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
14:14:45.123 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established[\r][\n]"
14:14:45.124 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
14:14:45.141 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
14:14:45.142 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.ConnectExec - ex-0000000001 tunnel to target created.
14:14:45.143 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000001 upgrading endpoint
14:14:45.605 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
14:14:45.606 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites: [TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
14:14:45.608 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake (null)
14:14:46.061 DEBUG jdk.event.security - X509Certificate: Alg:SHA256withRSA, Serial:426575a68c6f164cff53fc1fb6b05dda, Subject:CN=*.Test.com, O="ServiceNow, Inc.", L=San Diego, ST=California, C=US, Issuer:CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US, Key type:RSA, Length:2048, Cert Id:8860147, Valid from:1/24/24, 5:20 AM, Valid until:11/13/24, 5:20 AM
14:14:46.069 DEBUG jdk.event.security - X509Certificate: Alg:SHA256withRSA, Serial:ee94cc30000000051d37785, Subject:CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US, Issuer:CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US, Key type:RSA, Length:2048, Cert Id:-2068128596, Valid from:10/6/15, 12:43 AM, Valid until:12/6/30, 1:13 AM
14:14:46.078 DEBUG jdk.event.security - X509Certificate: Alg:SHA256withRSA, Serial:51d34044, Subject:CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US, Issuer:CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority, OU="(c) 2006 Entrust, Inc.", OU=www.entrust.net/CPS is incorporated by reference, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US, Key type:RSA, Length:2048, Cert Id:-1512125132, Valid from:9/22/14, 10:44 PM, Valid until:9/23/24, 7:01 AM
14:14:46.274 DEBUG jdk.event.security - ValidationChain: 1936920337, -2068128596, 8860147
14:14:46.432 DEBUG jdk.event.security -  TLSHandshake: test.org:8080, TLSv1.2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 8860147
14:14:46.433 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
14:14:46.434 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
14:14:46.435 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
14:14:46.436 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=*.Test.com, O="ServiceNow, Inc.", L=San Diego, ST=California, C=US
14:14:46.437 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [*.Test.com, Test.com, *.static.Test.com]
14:14:46.438 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
14:14:46.450 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.MainClientExec - ex-0000000001 executing GET /reltypes HTTP/1.1
14:14:46.452 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.p.RequestAddCookies - ex-0000000001 Cookie spec selected: strict
14:14:46.499 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000001 start execution ex-0000000001
14:14:46.500 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.i.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000001 executing exchange ex-0000000001 over http-outgoing-0
14:14:46.501 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> GET /reltypes HTTP/1.1
14:14:46.502 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: application/json
14:14:46.503 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> traceparent: 00-e15bfb0a6c3ba4f8a3a3d3a8d57a5e58-4e98abbb973d0224-00
14:14:46.504 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate
14:14:46.505 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: test.org
14:14:46.506 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: keep-alive
14:14:46.508 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.9)
14:14:46.510 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "GET /reltypes HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.512 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.513 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "traceparent: 00-e15bfb0a6c3ba4f8a3a3d3a8d57a5e58-4e98abbb973d0224-00[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.515 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.515 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: test.org[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.516 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.517 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.9)[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.518 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.617 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.618 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: snow_adc[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.620 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Fri, 07 Jun 2024 08:44:46 GMT[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.621 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.622 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.623 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.624 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Set-Cookie: BIGipServerpool_prod=5e229704765d26c7adbebbe45a38632a; httponly; secure; path=/; SameSite=None[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.625 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=D0A9B2EAF37376437FD9C5308E3A3A08; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.626 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server-Timing: sem_wait;dur=0, sesh_wait;dur=0[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.627 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.628 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Set-Cookie: glide_user=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.629 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Set-Cookie: glide_user_session=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.630 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="Test"[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.631 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Pragma: no-store,no-cache[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.632 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,max-age=-1[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.633 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Expires: 0[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.634 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.637 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.638 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "a[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.639 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x1f][0xffffff8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][\r][\n]"
14:14:46.641 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "69[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.644 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x1d][0xffffffcb][0xffffffc1][\r][0xffffffc2]0[0xc][0x5][0xffffffd0]U[0xffffffac][0x7f][0xffffffee][0x4][0xffffffbd][0xffffffb1][0x0][0x7]$[0x6][0xffffffb0][0xffffff9a]_[0xffffffb0]D[0xffffffe3][0xffffffe2]8\[0xffffffaa][0xffffffee]N[0xffffffd4][0xfffffffb]{[0x7][0x18][0xffffffe1][0xffffff81][0xfffffff9][0xffffffc0][0xffffffc6][0xffffffd6][0xfffffff4]E[0xffffffcc]x6[0xffffff86][0xffffffdc]=[0xffffffe5][0xffffffd6][0xfffffff3][0xffffffcd][0xffffff9a][0xffffffb6]h[0xffffffb2]`Ba[0xffffffaa]}[0xffffff86]x[0xfffffff0][0xffffffdb]-X$][0xfffffff6][0xfffffff0][0xffffff9f][0x15]^X[0xffffffac][0xffffffae][0x1e][0xffffff9b][0xffffffa6]y[0xffffffc5]9[0xffffffa1][0xffffffa5]fo#[0xffffffac][0xffffffe3][0xfffffff5] [0xffffffce]?[0xffffff8e][0xfffffff6]|[0x4]q[0x0][0x0][0x0][\r][\n]"
14:14:46.645 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "0[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.646 DEBUG o.a.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
14:14:46.649 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
14:14:46.652 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: snow_adc
14:14:46.653 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Fri, 07 Jun 2024 08:44:46 GMT
14:14:46.654 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
14:14:46.655 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
14:14:46.656 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: keep-alive
14:14:46.657 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: BIGipServerpool_prod=5e229704765d26c7adbebbe45a38632a; httponly; secure; path=/; SameSite=None
14:14:46.658 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=D0A9B2EAF37376437FD9C5308E3A3A08; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None
14:14:46.659 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server-Timing: sem_wait;dur=0, sesh_wait;dur=0
14:14:46.660 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Encoding: gzip
14:14:46.661 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: glide_user=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None
14:14:46.663 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: glide_user_session=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None
14:14:46.664 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="Test"
14:14:46.664 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Pragma: no-store,no-cache
14:14:46.665 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,max-age=-1
14:14:46.666 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Expires: 0
14:14:46.668 DEBUG o.a.h.client5.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
14:14:46.692 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.p.ResponseProcessCookies - ex-0000000001 Cookie accepted [BIGipServerpool_prod="5e229704765d26c7adbebbe45a38632a", domain:test.org, path:/, expiry:null]
14:14:46.694 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.p.ResponseProcessCookies - ex-0000000001 Cookie accepted [JSESSIONID="D0A9B2EAF37376437FD9C5308E3A3A08", domain:test.org, path:/, expiry:null]
14:14:46.696 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.p.ResponseProcessCookies - ex-0000000001 Cookie accepted [glide_user="", domain:test.org, path:/, expiry:2024-06-07T08:44:46.695137400Z]
14:14:46.699 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.p.ResponseProcessCookies - ex-0000000001 Cookie accepted [glide_user_session="", domain:test.org, path:/, expiry:2024-06-07T08:44:46.699141200Z]
14:14:46.721 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.MainClientExec - ex-0000000001 connection can be kept alive for 3 MINUTES
14:14:46.726 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.a.HttpAuthenticator - ex-0000000001 Authentication required
14:14:46.730 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.a.HttpAuthenticator - ex-0000000001 test.org:443 requested authentication
14:14:46.735 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.DefaultAuthenticationStrategy - ex-0000000001 Authentication schemes in the order of preference: [Negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, Digest, Basic]
14:14:46.736 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.DefaultAuthenticationStrategy - ex-0000000001 Challenge for Negotiate authentication scheme not available
14:14:46.738 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.DefaultAuthenticationStrategy - ex-0000000001 Challenge for Kerberos authentication scheme not available
14:14:46.739 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.DefaultAuthenticationStrategy - ex-0000000001 Challenge for NTLM authentication scheme not available
14:14:46.740 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.DefaultAuthenticationStrategy - ex-0000000001 Challenge for Digest authentication scheme not available
14:14:46.741 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.a.HttpAuthenticator - ex-0000000001 Selecting authentication options
14:14:46.744 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.a.BasicScheme - ex-0000000001 No credentials found for auth scope [Basic 'Test' https://test.org:443]
14:23:10.013 ERROR o.t.c.s.i.ServiceNowService - org.apache.hc.client5.http.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream@54ab0e39
14:23:10.031 ERROR o.t.c.s.i.ServiceNowService - [Server:"snow_adc", Date:"Fri, 07 Jun 2024 08:44:46 GMT", Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Connection:"keep-alive", Set-Cookie:"BIGipServerpool_prod=5e229704765d26c7adbebbe45a38632a; httponly; secure; path=/; SameSite=None", "JSESSIONID=D0A9B2EAF37376437FD9C5308E3A3A08; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", "glide_user=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", "glide_user_session=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", Set-Cookie:"BIGipServerpool_prod=5e229704765d26c7adbebbe45a38632a; httponly; secure; path=/; SameSite=None", "JSESSIONID=D0A9B2EAF37376437FD9C5308E3A3A08; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", "glide_user=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", "glide_user_session=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", Server-Timing:"sem_wait;dur=0, sesh_wait;dur=0", Set-Cookie:"BIGipServerpool_prod=5e229704765d26c7adbebbe45a38632a; httponly; secure; path=/; SameSite=None", "JSESSIONID=D0A9B2EAF37376437FD9C5308E3A3A08; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", "glide_user=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", "glide_user_session=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", Set-Cookie:"BIGipServerpool_prod=5e229704765d26c7adbebbe45a38632a; httponly; secure; path=/; SameSite=None", "JSESSIONID=D0A9B2EAF37376437FD9C5308E3A3A08; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", "glide_user=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", "glide_user_session=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; secure; SameSite=None", WWW-Authenticate:"BASIC realm="Test"", Pragma:"no-store,no-cache", Cache-Control:"no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,max-age=-1", Expires:"0", Strict-Transport-Security:"max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"]
14:23:10.032 ERROR o.t.c.s.i.ServiceNowService - Unauthorized
14:23:10.034 ERROR o.t.c.s.i.ServiceNowService - 401 UNAUTHORIZED
14:23:10.067 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.c.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000001 releasing valid endpoint


There is far too little information here. How are you using the client, what is the response/error you get (in your logs). Also I would use HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient) instead of calling the setter. Also you are using Spring Boot, which already configures a RestClient.Builder. Re-use that (and if this configuration is needed globally add a customizer for this).

Updated the question with log and rest api code.@M.Deinum how could i add proxy to RestClient.Builder. I could use Basic authentication interpreter for basic authenticaiton as stated in another thread.

Have you read the error? 14:14:46.744 DEBUG o.a.h.c.h.i.a.BasicScheme - ex-0000000001 No credentials found for auth scope [Basic 'Test' https://test.org:443]  seems pretty clear to me.

If you are injecting username and password as values, ensure that they are correctly populated: new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password). I ran your scenario successfully using org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5 I assume you used 4, but it should be similar.
